# SQL Cumulative Sum of 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

INPUT:

```
| ID |    Class | SubDate  | RecDate   | SubAmt| RecAmt|
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       123| 23/08/15 | 15/10/2015| 12710 | 10613 |
|  2 |       123| 23/09/15 | NULL      | 12710 | NULL  |
|  3 |       123| 23/10/15 | NULL      | 2096  | NULL  |
|  4 |       123| 23/11/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  |
|  5 |       123| 23/12/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  |
|  6 |       123| 23/01/16 | 03/03/2016| 83913 | 78416 |
|  7 |       123| 23/02/16 | 19/04/2016| 267688| 168507|
|  8 |       123| 23/03/16 | 24/05/2016| 217168| 10891 |
|  9 |       123| 25/04/16 | NULL      | 48661 | NULL  |
| 10 |       123| 25/05/16 | 04/07/2016| 67824 | 47921 |
| 11 |       123| 23/06/16 | 07/08/2016|111612 | 35782 |
| 12 |       123| 25/07/16 | NULL      | 63691 | NULL  |
| 13 |       123| 25/08/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  |
| 14 |       123| 25/09/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  |
| 15 |       224| 26/05/16 | 25/07/2016| 41325 | 33075 |
| 16 |       224| 20/06/16 | 29/08/2016| 41325 | 5875  |
| 17 |       224| 20/07/16 | NULL      | 41325 | NULL  |
| 18 |       224| 18/08/16 | NULL      | 8250  | NULL  |
| 19 |       224| 20/09/16 | NULL      | 2375  | NULL  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

My condition that I have to set is:

```
CASE WHEN SubDate > RecDate THEN (SubAmt + RecAmt) 
ELSE SubAmt 
END AS Cumulative
```

Example 1:
As you can see from Desired Output,

For ID 1: 23/08/15 (SubDate of ID 1) < than 15/10/2015 (RecDate of ID 1). Hence, Cumulative for ID 1 = 12710 (SubAmt of ID 1).

Example 2:
For ID 3: 23/10/15 (SubDate of ID 3) > 15/10/2015 (RecDate of ID 1). Hence, Cumulative for ID 3 = 2096 (SubAmt of ID 3)  + 10613 (RecAmt of ID 1) = 12710.

Example 3:
For ID 8,  23/03/16 (SubDate of ID 8) > the RecDate of ID 1 & 6
                                           15/10/2015 (RecDate of ID 1)
                                           03/03/2016 (RecDate of ID 6)

Hence, the cumulative for ID 8: 217168 (SubAmt of ID 3) + 10613 (ID 1) + 78416 (ID 6) = 306197

Desired Output:

```
| ID |    Class | SubDate  | RecDate   | SubAmt| RecAmt| Cumulative
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       123| 23/08/15 | 15/10/2015| 12710 | 10613 | 12710 
|  2 |       123| 23/09/15 | NULL      | 12710 | NULL  | 12710 
|  3 |       123| 23/10/15 | NULL      | 2096  | NULL  | 12710 
|  4 |       123| 23/11/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  | 11530
|  5 |       123| 23/12/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  | 11530
|  6 |       123| 23/01/16 | 03/03/2016| 83913 | 78416 | 94527
|  7 |       123| 23/02/16 | 19/04/2016| 267688| 168507| 278302
|  8 |       123| 23/03/16 | 24/05/2016| 217168| 10891 | 306197
|  9 |       123| 25/04/16 | NULL      | 48661 | NULL  | 306197
| 10 |       123| 25/05/16 | 04/07/2016| 67824 | 47921 | 336252
| 11 |       123| 23/06/16 | 07/08/2016|111612 | 35782 | 380040
| 12 |       123| 25/07/16 | NULL      | 63691 | NULL  | 380040
| 13 |       123| 25/08/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  | 382820
| 14 |       123| 25/09/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  | 382820
| 15 |       224| 26/05/16 | 25/07/2016| 41325 | 33075 | 41325
| 16 |       224| 20/06/16 | 29/08/2016| 41325 | 5875  | 41325
| 17 |       224| 20/07/16 | NULL      | 41325 | NULL  | 41325
| 18 |       224| 18/08/16 | NULL      | 8250  | NULL  | 41325
| 19 |       224| 20/09/16 | NULL      | 2375  | NULL  | 41325
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please kindly advise.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT [ID]
,[Class]
,[SubDate]
,[RecDate]
,[SubAmt]
,[RecAmt]
,SUM (CASE 
        WHEN SubDate  > RecDate  or RecDate   IS NULL THEN (SubAmt + RecAmt)  
        ELSE SubAmt  END ) OVER (PARTITION BY [Class] ORDER BY [ID] ROWS 
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cumulative
FROM TableName
```

But it does not work and it instead gives me an output which does not fit to the requirement.

Wrong Output:

```
| ID |    Class | SubDate  | RecDate   | SubAmt| RecAmt| Cumulative (Wrong Output)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       123| 23/08/15 | 15/10/2015| 12710 | 10613 | 12710
|  2 |       123| 23/09/15 | NULL      | 12710 | NULL  | 12710
|  3 |       123| 23/10/15 | NULL      | 2096  | NULL  | 12710
|  4 |       123| 23/11/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  | 12710
|  5 |       123| 23/12/15 | NULL      |  917  | NULL  | 12710
|  6 |       123| 23/01/16 | 03/03/2016| 83913 | 78416 | 96623
|  7 |       123| 23/02/16 | 19/04/2016| 267688| 168507| 364312
|  8 |       123| 23/03/16 | 24/05/2016| 217168| 10891 | 581480
|  9 |       123| 25/04/16 | NULL      | 48661 | NULL  | 581480
| 10 |       123| 25/05/16 | 04/07/2016| 67824 | 47921 | 649304
| 11 |       123| 23/06/16 | 07/08/2016|111612 | 35782 | 760917
| 12 |       123| 25/07/16 | NULL      | 63691 | NULL  | 760917
| 13 |       123| 25/08/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  | 760917
| 14 |       123| 25/09/16 | NULL      | 30688 | NULL  | 760917
| 15 |       224| 26/05/16 | 25/07/2016| 41325 | 33075 | 41325
| 16 |       224| 20/06/16 | 29/08/2016| 41325 | 5875  | 82650
| 17 |       224| 20/07/16 | NULL      | 41325 | NULL  | 82650
| 18 |       224| 18/08/16 | NULL      | 8250  | NULL  | 82650
| 19 |       224| 20/09/16 | NULL      | 2375  | NULL  | 82650
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me to kindly advise how I should change the SQL code as well as how i should fit the case statement. Thanks everyone!

Comment: 'Hence, Cumulative for ID 3 = 2096 (SubAmt of ID 3) + 10613 (RecAmt of ID 1) = 12710' Only if your calculator is very broken...

Comment: There is actually supposed to be decimals after some of the amounts but I cut it out for easier viewing of data. Hope you understand that there will be at least a difference of +-1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When `RecDate` is `NULL`, then `SubDate > RecDate` condition will fail since `NULL` is unknown and cannot be compared against any value.

Try something like this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN SubDate > RecDate or RecDate IS NULL THEN (SubAmt + RecAmt) 
ELSE SubAmt 
END AS Cumulative) OVER(PARTITION BY [Class] ORDER BY [ID] ROWS BETWEEN 
UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for advising. However, as referred to the "Wrong Output:" section above, I have tried your solution and the output is still a bit far from the expected output.